# Move an element in an arc while scrolling

Tags: jquery, css

So, I'm trying to move a circle in an arc across my container while scrolling.

Basically, while I scroll down I want this ball to move over a drawing of a city (the circle/ball being the sun).

Scrolling down should bring the sun across, while scrolling up should move it the other way.

It should have a slight arc to the movement.

I've been fiddling with CSS transforms for a couple days with no luck, so I'm hoping someone can help me out.

I'm using this code below to rotate some cogs on the same page while scrolling, so I assume it would be somewhat similar, but instead of rotate, it would be moving and arcing the sun.

```
jQuery(function() {
    var rotation = 0, 
    scrollLoc = jQuery(document).scrollTop();
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        var newLoc = jQuery(document).scrollTop();
        var diff = scrollLoc - newLoc;
        rotation += diff, scrollLoc = newLoc;
        var rotationStr = "rotate(" + rotation + "deg)";
        jQuery(".cog").css({
            "-webkit-transform": rotationStr,
            "-moz-transform": rotationStr,
            "transform": rotationStr
        });
    });
});
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: i think you need an invisible circle and the sun placed within that circle

Comment: `var rotationStr = "rotate(" + rotation + "deg) translate(" + circle_radius + "px)";` Or set the transform origin outside your circle.